# Exception: В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект

Tags: c#, .net, исключения

Основная задача программы - сменить MachineGuid. При выполнении программы выбивает такая ошибка - Exception: В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

class MachineGuidChanger
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string key = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography";
        string r = (string)Registry.GetValue(key, "MachineGuid", (object)"default");
        Console.WriteLine("Current MachineGuid: " + r);
        try
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Backup.txt");
            sw.WriteLine("Old MachineGuid: " + r);
            sw.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
        Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
        try
        {
            RegistryKey savKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography");
            savKey.SetValue("MachineGuid", g);
            savKey.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
        string newkey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography";
        string newr = (string)Registry.GetValue(newkey, "MachineGuid", (object)"default");
        Console.WriteLine("New MachineGuid: " + newr);
    }
}
```

Comment: В какой строке - надо догадаться? Позвонил Ванге, сказала, вам нужно собрать приложение под x64 архитектуру, а не под Any CPU. А так же запускать это от имени Администратора.

Comment: И это не `Exception`, а `NullReferenceException` -  `Console.WriteLine($"{e.GetType().Name}: {e.Message}");`

Comment: И вот это вот еще надо поменять `RegistryKey savKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key, true);`